# BigContentView in android notification (4.1 +) in samsung tablet

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-touchwiz

I am using big-contentview for notification message using remoteViews.
That big content view shows good in nexus 7 but in Samsung 10" tablet showing like collapsed layout. And other application like Google play music shows only collapsed notification only.

I tested with SM-T520 (10" tablet)

1) Wther no support for bigcontentview in tablet/samsung.

2) Or how to handle to show a collapsed notification in such a condition.

1st Pic : This is the samsung tablet screen, that bigcontentview not fully visible.

[image: This is the samsung tablet screen, that bigcontentview not fully visible.]

2nd Pic : Expected Output.

[image: Expected Output]

**layout-v16 I had expand layout.**

**layout-v11 I had collapsed layout.**

Code (Java) :

```
     mNotificationTemplate = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.notification_download_latest);

    if (NotificationHelper.hasHoneycomb()) { // Notification Builder
        mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(mContext, url))
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setOngoing(true).setContent(mNotificationTemplate).build();
        if (NotificationHelper.hasJellyBean()) {
            // Expanded notifiction style
            // mExpandedView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), //
            // R.layout.notification_download_latest);

            **mNotification.bigContentView = mNotificationTemplate;**
            mNotificationTemplate.setOnClickPendingIntent(
                    R.id.notification_cancelBtn,
                    getPendingIntent(mContext, url));
```

Comment: Once swipe down in a big-content notification became expanded layout.

Answer (score 6):

On the Samsung, your `Notification` is not at the top. Only the top-most `Notification` will be automatically shown expanded.

Hence, the behavior is perfectly normal.

Comment: Wther we can open with expanded view with Priority to HIGH ?

Comment: @Ashraf: That would increase the odds that it will be at the top, but it depends entirely on what other notifications are already visible.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can we prevent notification from collepse means close? if it is not on the top.

Comment: @MayurRaval: Sorry, but I do not know what you are referring to. You may wish to consider asking your own Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set priority:

```
mNotification.priority=NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX;
```

Comment: Finally I moved with this priority to show the notification without collapse.

Comment: Thank you, after an hour of tinkering around with remote views and bigContentView without success I finally found this!